# How to solve this variadic template ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

The following code compiles and runs fine as long as `someFuncTemplate(func1)` is commented out. However, once it is uncommented, compilation fails with the error " 'value' is not a member of 'Arity<int (*)(int, int)>' " compile error, which I believe is due to the compiler selecting the first template instead of the second one at `Arity<F>::value`. I tried removing the brackets from the first template, but the issue remains, just this time with an "incomplete type" compilation error.

How can I force the compiler to select the correct template when I use `Arity<F>`?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Arity {};

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct Arity<Ret(Args...)>
    : std::integral_constant<size_t, sizeof...(Args)> 
{};

int func1(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

template <typename F>
void someFuncTemplate(F)
{
    std::cout << Arity<F>::value;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << Arity<decltype(func1)>::value << '\n';
    //someFuncTemplate(func1);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add another specialization for the second case:

```cpp
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct Arity<Ret (*)(Args...)> : Arity<Ret(Args...)> {};
//               ^^^
```

You could also add

```cpp
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct Arity<Ret (&)(Args...)> : Arity<Ret(Args...)> {};
```

in order to make a function declaration such as the below working:

```cpp
template <typename F>
void someFuncTemplate(F&&) {
    std::cout << Arity<F>::value;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mbhbvjas8)

Comment: well, that was simpler than I expected. What is the difference between Ret(Args...) and Ret(*)(Args...)?

Comment: @Janilson It's the type of `F` when you pass the function as an argument to the function instead of doing `decltype` on it like you do in `main`. `someFuncTemplate(func1);` is the same as `someFuncTemplate(&func1);`

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to adding a specialization for a pointer to function, you could modify `someFunctTemplate` to take its argument by reference:

```cpp
// preceding unchanged

template <typename F>
void someFuncTemplate(F const &)
//......................^^^^^^^
{
    std::cout << Arity<F>::value;
}

int main()
{
    someFuncTemplate(func1);
}
```